# initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]

Tags: c

i just started to learn how to program and i encountered this error that goes like this: "initialization makes integer from pointer without a cast [enabled by default]"
What is the problem?

```
 // This program pairs three kids with their favorite superhero
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
char Kid1[12];
// Kid1 can hold an 11-character name
// Kid2 will be 7 characters (Maddie plus null 0)
char Kid2[] = "Maddie";
// Kid3 is also 7 characters, but specifically defined
char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";
// Hero1 will be 7 characters (adding null 0!)
char Hero1 = "Batman";
// Hero2 will have extra room just in case
char Hero2[34] = "Spiderman";
char Hero3[25];
Kid1[0] = 'K';  //Kid1 is being defined character-by-character
Kid1[1] = 'a';  //Not efficient, but it does work
Kid1[2] = 't';
Kid1[3] = 'i';
Kid1[4] = 'e';
Kid1[5] = '\0';  // Never forget the null 0 so C knows when the
// string ends
strcpy(Hero3, "The Incredible Hulk");


printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid2, Hero2);
printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid3, Hero3);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Whatever you do **DO NOT ADD A CAST**!! The error message could be improved a lot :)

Comment: `//Not efficient, but it does work` - this suggests that you are already worrying about efficiency. **Don't!** At least not while you're an absolute beginner.

Answer (score 7):

The problem is with `char Hero1 = "Batman"`:

- When you use a double-quoted string of characters in your code, the compiler replaces it with a pointer to the beginning of the memory space in which the string will reside during runtime.
- So by `char Hero1 = "Batman"`, you are actually attempting to assign a memory address (which typically consists of 32 or 64 bits of data, depending on your system) into a character variable (which typically stores 8 bits of data).

In order to fix the problem, you need to change it to either one of the following options:

- `char  Hero1[] = "Batman"`
- `char* Hero1   = "Batman"`

---

FYI, in both cases above, the string `"Batman"` will reside in a read-only memory section during runtime.

However, there is a notable difference between these two cases:

- Using `char Hero1[]`, the `"Batman"` string will be copied into the stack every time the function is called. The `Hero1` array will start at that address, and you will be able to change the contents of that array at a later point within the function.
- Using `char* Hero1`, the `"Batman"` string will **not** be copied into the stack every time the function is called. The `Hero1` variable will be pointing to the original address of the string, hence you will **not** will be able to change the contents of that string at any point within the function.

---

When the executable image is generated from your code, the string is **placed** in the code-section, which is one of several memory-sections within the program. The compiler then replaces the so-called "string assignment" with a so-called "integer assignment".

For example, `char* x = "abc"` is changed into `char* x = (char*)0x82004000` before being compiled into object code, where `0x82004000` is the (constant) address of the string in the program's memory space.

When you do `sizeof("abc")`, the executable image **will not even contain** the `"abc"` string, since there is no "runtime" operation performed on this string.

There is no object code generated for `sizeof` - the compiler computes this value **during compilation**, and immediately replaces it **with a constant**.

You can look into the (intermediate) map file that is usually generated, and see that the input string of that `sizeof` operation **does not** appear anywhere.

Answer (score 3):

```
char Hero1 = "Batman";
```

should be

```
char Hero1[] = "Batman";
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple times you have some issues:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
main()
{
    char Kid1[12];
    // Kid1 can hold an 11-character name
    // Kid2 will be 7 characters (Maddie plus null 0)
    char Kid2[] = "Maddie";
    // Kid3 is also 7 characters, but specifically defined
    char Kid3[7] = "Andrew";
    // Hero1 will be 7 characters (adding null 0!)
    char *Hero1 = "Batman"; //needs to be a pointer
    // Hero2 will have extra room just in case
    char *Hero2 = "Spiderman"; //needs to be a pointer
    char Hero3[25]
    Kid1[0] = 'K';  //Kid1 is being defined character-by-character
    Kid1[1] = 'a';  //Not efficient, but it does work
    Kid1[2] = 't';
    Kid1[3] = 'i';
    Kid1[4] = 'e';
    Kid1[5] = '\0';  // Never forget the null 0 so C knows when the
                  // string ends
    strcpy(Hero3, "The Incredible Hulk");


    printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid1, Hero1);
    printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid2, Hero2);
    printf("%s\'s favorite hero is %s.\n", Kid3, Hero3);
    return 0;
}
```

You should define all of your vars at the top of the function, its a good C practice.

Other than that, I flagged the issues (and corrected them) with comments.

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

This error you get because **String data type is not in C**
programming **you can print string by using array or char pointer** like

1.**Array**:

```
  #include<stdio.h>
   int main(){
   char  a[]={'a','b','c','d','f','\0'};
   printf("%s",a);
   return 0;
   }
```

[Click here to check the output of solution array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hx7ld.png)

2.**char pointer**:

```
    #include<stdio.h>
     int main(){
     char*  a="abcd";
     printf("%s",a);
     return 0;
     }
```

[Click here to check the output of solution char pointer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y2azC.png)

Comment: The first version is not correct. C will not null-terminate the array automatically. You need to do `char a[] = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'f', '\0'};`

Comment: Also, please work on fixing the indentation and formatting of your answer.

Comment: sir first program shows why that error occurred in your program and the rest of two is the solution to resolve it

Comment: I'm not the OP (this question was posted 6 years ago btw), I was commenting on this post since it was flagged as a low-quality answer, advising you to [fix up the formatting in the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help). The bug I am referring to is for the solution you proposed using the array, which is invalid C, please check again.

Comment: sir all solutions are in working condition i also attached screenshots of my codes and output i checked that code on programiz C compiler and also changed format of my answer

Comment: Please refer to my original comment, "C will not null-terminate the array automatically" -- you are missing a null terminator `'\0'`. The code can crash in such a case, though it may appear to work out of luck on some systems in some cases, you can read more about it in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40821419/when-why-is-0-necessary-to-mark-end-of-an-char-array). You can also verify this is a bug if you compile with address sanitizer extensions.

Comment: thank you for your support sir I corrected my code